# Facebook Marketing API (ads) for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I want to create a rails application that can create facebooks ads automatically. So I need to use the Facebook Marketing Api.

It seems that there are a lot of ressources for the Graph Api but I didn't find simple ressources for the Marketing Api. I only found Php and Python on Facebook website.

I found some rails gems but there is no documentation and they don't seem to be well updated.

https://github.com/oguzcanhuner/eucalyptus

https://github.com/moviepilot/zuck

I'm not a confirmed developper and I need some help/ressources to start this. 
How am i supposed to do that ? Is there someone who managed to do it ? or someone that used these gems ?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but you are asking for "some help/ressources to start this." and _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._

Answer (score 2):

Facebook has released their in house/official `facebookads` gem last month to facilitate application development for Facebook Ads API using Ruby.

You can see the complete documentation for the same [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-ads-sdk).

`facebookads` gem covers all features in more detail as compared to the earlier gem `facebook_ads`.

I will suggest you go for official `facebookads` gem as it is just released, code quality and feature coverage is better and ofcourse it being official gem will have better support.

The best thing is facebook also have released exact same sdk in other languages also([for python](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk)), so it makes it very easy if you have build exact same functionality in some other language or if you are porting your application from some other language. In my case i am porting from `python` to `ruby` and found that both the sdk's allow using Facebook Ads API in exactly similar fashion and even project structure is also exactly the same :)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `facebook_ads` gem:

`gem install facebook_ads`

Or

`gem 'facebook_ads', '~> 0.1'`

The documentation is available [here](https://github.com/cte/facebook-ruby-ads-sdk).